# Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected after each screen resize

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating responsive navbar and it works well while rendering. After each screen resize or switching to mobile view I get error: "Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement."

```
  133 | 
  134 |  useEffect(() => {
  135 |    const setResponsiveness = () => {
> 136 |      return window.innerWidth < 900
  137 | ^         ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
  138 |        : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
  139 |    };
  140 | 
  141 |    setResponsiveness();
  142 | 
> 143 |    window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
  144 | ^ }, []);
  145 | 
  146 |  const displayDesktop = () => {
```

After checking window width I just want to change state of mobile view to false or true and then call displayDesktop or displayMobile function.

Shortcode with the most important parts:

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const {
    header,
    toolbar,
    drawerContainer,
    largeIcon,
    logo,
    desktopList,
  } = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    mobileView: false,
    drawerOpen: false,
  });

  const { mobileView, drawerOpen } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    const setResponsiveness = () => {
      return window.innerWidth < 900
        ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
        : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
    };

    setResponsiveness();

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
  }, []);

  const displayDesktop = () => {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Toolbar className={toolbar}>
          <div className={logo}>
            <MotorcycleRoundedIcon className={largeIcon} fontSize="large" />
            <Typography variant="h6" fontFamily="Arial" color="inherit" noWrap>
              Title
            </Typography>
          </div>
          <div className={desktopList}>
            {GetStatsButton()} {GetResultsButton()} {GetTablesButton()}
            {GetCalendarButton()}
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  };

  const displayMobile = () => {
    const handleDrawerOpen = () =>
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, drawerOpen: true }));
    const handleDrawerClose = () =>
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, drawerOpen: false }));

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            {...{
              edge: "start",
              color: "inherit",
              "aria-label": "menu",
              "aria-haspopup": "true",
              onClick: handleDrawerOpen,
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>

          <Drawer
            {...{
              anchor: "top",
              open: drawerOpen,
              onClose: handleDrawerClose,
              variant: "temporary",
            }}
          >
            <div className={drawerContainer}>{getDrawerChoices()}</div>
          </Drawer>
          <MotorcycleRoundedIcon className={largeIcon} fontSize="large" />
          <Typography variant="h6" fontFamily="Arial" color="inherit" noWrap>
            Title
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <AppBar className={header}>
        {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
      </AppBar>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Could someone give me a hint? I know it has something to do with calling Hooks inside conditions, but I have no idea how to reformat it.

Comment: I don't think this section of your code has a problem. It seems to be working fine it might be something to do with the other Components you have. disable each on of them until the error disappears and then you'll track it down.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lichterman-q3b0z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling React hooks from a regular JS function, which violates the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). You do this when calling, for example, `GetStatsButton()`, since all these components include `useSate` calls.

You can fix this by changing:

```js
<div className={desktopList}>
  {GetStatsButton()} {GetResultsButton()} {GetTablesButton()}
  {GetCalendarButton()}
</div>
```

to

```js
<div className={desktopList}>
  <GetStatsButton />
  <GetResultsButton />
  <GetTablesButton />
  <GetCalendarButton />
</div>
```

To highlight the fact that these are React components, it would be good practice to remove the *Get* from the name.

Additionally, your `StyledMenuItem` and `StyledMenu` should be defined only once **outside** these components, and you can then reuse them anywhere you need them.

Last but not least, you may want to take a look at MUI's [useMediaQuery](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/) to achieve your desired responsive behavior.